# Laravel migration not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5

I tried to implement the default auth login system in laravel

```
      php artisan make:migration create_users_table
      Created Migration: 2016_03_10_115611_create_users_table
```

On running the above command only migration file is created and  not the tables are created.
Also i have tried to reinstall composer but it didn't work

```
//In 2016_03_10_115611_create_users_table file
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 }

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

on running

```
php artisan migrate
```

it took a few amounts of time and returned

```
[ErrorException]PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away
```

Thanks to everyone i have not configured the .env file properly so  that it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your MySQL version?
Or you not yet modify .env

Try SQLite and change settings database to sqlite. I think this problem on php extension.

Answer (score 1):

First you have run this command to install migration

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

Note :- if you look at database/migrations there will be already two migrations files

1. 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
2. 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php

   php artisan migrate